# How to restrict user from key in other values in autocomplete textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

Sorry I'm new to jquery and i dont know whether this logic is possible to be applied or not? Hope can get some guidances. I've a completed autocomplete textbox, but how can i restrict the user from key in the value to the textbox? The way of doing this because i need to store the description to the database, unfortunately when user select the list items from textbox they are able edit the description of items. How to prevent this ? Any helps would be appreciated.

Jsfiddle: `Sample` [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/VvETA/75/)

Comment: I know. But if i make readonly how can i input the value to list out the items? i can make it readonly for PRICE,QTY,COLOR.. but user can edit the items name.

Answer (score 0):

Just add disabled attribute to input field which you don't want to change.

You can add like this:

```
<div class="ui-widget">
    <label for="tags">Items:</label>
    <input id="tags" /><br/><br/><br/>
    <label for="tags">Color:</label>
    <input id="COLOR" disabled="disabled" /><br/><br/>
    <label for="tags">PRICE:</label>
    <input id="PRICE" disabled="disabled" /><br/><br/>
    <label for="tags">QTY  :</label>
    <input id="QTY" disabled="disabled" />
</div>
```

Comment: Not working.. even tough COLOR,PRICE,QTY are disabled. BUT items description still can be change

Comment: For item description you can use select box instead of text box.

Answer (score 0):

Modify  your autocomplete function to make the fields readonly on select. You will also need to clear those fields if user unselects:

```
   $("#tags").autocomplete({
      source: availableTags,
      focus: function (event, ui) 
      {
            event.preventDefault();
            $("#tags").val(ui.item.label);
        },
      select: function (event, ui) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $("#COLOR").val(ui.item.value);
            $("#COLOR").attr('readonly',true);
            $("#PRICE").val(ui.item.value2);
            $("#PRICE").attr('readonly',true);
            $("#QTY").val(ui.item.value3);
            $("#QTY").attr('readonly',true);
            $("#tags").val(ui.item.label);
        }
    });
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/VvETA/76/)

Comment: Not working. I know the QTY, PRICE,COLOR are readonly. but item still can be edit